# When fgets is dangerous (with the size less than buffer size)?

Tags: c, fgets

```
FILE * file = fopen( “in.txt”, “r” );
char line[80];
if( NULL != file ) {
    fgets( line, 40, file );
    fclose( file );
}
```

Is there anything dangerous in the above code, what i saw here was it got the maximum length 40 string to the buffer line then close the file.

Comment: no there isn't, why are you thinking that it is dangerous?

Comment: You mean gets? fgets() is safer if you compare with gets()

Comment: Are you sure that you understand `fgets()`? Did you read `fgets()` [Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)? What exactly is `40` in your `fgets()`call?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre oh okay, it's just a question from a review and i want to make sure if i miss sth or not.

Comment: @Michi keep calm, i just want to make sure, 40 is just 40, that's the point of the question, whether the size used in fgets less than the buffer size.

Comment: For `fgets`, in your example, unless you have a _special_ reason not to, the idiomatic [recommended] call is: `fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)`. Using a shorter length is okay [just wasteful]. Using a longer length is undefined behavior [and will probably segfault]

Comment: @CraigEstey ah okay, i got it now, tysm.

Comment: @CraigEstey it segfaults only if some line is longer than the buffer length.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing the needed #include statement for the needed header file.  When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, always post a [mcve].

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre,  Having a line in the file that is longer than the length given to `fgets()` will NOT cause a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be confusing `fgets()` and `gets()`. See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

As long as the size param matches the buffer size, `fgets` is safe. In your case it would be normal to do `fgets( line, sizeof(line), file );`
Note: `fgets()` reads at most 1 less than "size" and always 0 terminates.